# HTML object - putting videos into webpage - cant stop AUTOSTART

Tags: html, css, flash, object, video

Ok.. having some real trouble putting two SWF videos into a website for my uni assignment. I can't stop the videos from autostarting, I have set the autostart parameter to false but still no luck

```
<div id="video">
<br /><br />
    <span class="maincontentttitle">Touch&egrave;!</span><br /><br />
        <OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            WIDTH="425"
            HEIGHT="349"
            CODEBASE="http://active.macromedia.com/flash5/cabs/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0">
                <PARAM NAME="MOVIE" VALUE="video1.swf">
                <PARAM NAME="PLAY" VALUE="true">
                <PARAM NAME="LOOP" VALUE="true">
                <PARAM NAME="QUALITY" VALUE="high">
                <PARAM NAME="SCALE" value="noborder">
                <PARAM NAME="AUTOSTART" value="false">
                    <EMBED SRC="video1.swf"
                        WIDTH="425"
                        HEIGHT="349"
                        PLAY="true" 
                        LOOP="true"
                        QUALITY="high" 
                        scale="noborder"
                        AUTOSTART="false"
                        PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"> 
                    </EMBED>
        </OBJECT>
    <br /><br />
    <span class="maincontentttitle">Students On Politics</span>
<br /><br />
        <OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            WIDTH="647"
            HEIGHT="364"
            CODEBASE="http://active.macromedia.com/flash5/cabs/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0">
                <PARAM NAME="MOVIE" VALUE="video2.swf">
                <PARAM NAME="PLAY" VALUE="true">
                <PARAM NAME="LOOP" VALUE="true">
                <PARAM NAME="QUALITY" VALUE="high">
                <PARAM NAME="SCALE" value="noborder">
                <PARAM NAME="AUTOSTART" value="false">
                    <EMBED SRC="video2.swf"
                        WIDTH="647"
                        HEIGHT="364"
                        PLAY="true" 
                        LOOP="true"
                        QUALITY="high" 
                        scale="noborder"
                        AUTOSTART="false"
                        PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"> 
                    </EMBED>
        </OBJECT>
```

Thank you in advance if you are able to help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the FLA file you could just put a stop action on the first frame and a listener event for when someone clicks the play button, and then start the video when the event is triggered. The video would then be on the 2nd frame.

Otherwise i really don't know. What you have done should stop it from autoplaying.

Comment: strange isnt it... yeah I think I shall do that then... Thank you